# Can you become a Thane of Riften if Wujeeta dies before you complete a required quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Can you still become a Thane of Riften if Wujeeta dies before telling you about the skooma? I was just starting to ask her when a dragon came down and wrecked everything.

Can I become a Thane of Riften even though Wujeeta died before I could finish this required quest?

Answer (score 5):

Nope, The Skooma Trade is the opening quest to Becoming a Thane of Riften, so you have to finish it before being able to start the quests leading to being Thane. Resurrecting her will still consider her dead, whether you use magic or the console.

From then, your choices are:

- Pick a previous save, before the dragon
- If on computer, you can force start the quest using the console (~ key), and the `command setstage FreeformRiftenThane 10` ; save before doing it though, just in case

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the Empire takes control of the Rift you will become thane fairly easily. It can happen either via the civil war quests or the main quest, during the peace council.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not the best way to get there, but you can revive the NPC using the console.

Go into the console, use the mouse to click on his body, then type in `resurrect` and hit enter.

(There is a Guardian Stone outside of Whiterun that teaches you to raise the dead. But I believe they turn into zombies instead, which is not what you want here.)

Comment: That would only work for PC though, no console on consoles.

Answer (score 0):

If you are playing on a PC, use these console commands:

`SetStage FreeForm12 10` - This is where you are if Wujeeta asked for a healing potion.

Assuming Wujeeta is dead, then:

`SetStage FreeForm12 20` - Not sure what it does, but I did it on the way to the next step.  Can't hurt.

`SetStage FreeForm12 25` - Gets you the reward.  Enter Riften proper, then go back to the docks area. Wujeeta should be wandering around now and you can continue on with the quest line.

Comment: Can you complete your answer, and mention how to get to the console and use these commands? Without it, it's very vague.