# How to become Thane of Riften if the required NPC died before starting the quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was playing, and then either a dragon or a random fight accidentally killed the NPC and I don't know where or when it happened.

I'm playing a modded version on PS4.

Comment: I thought every NPC that has questline got Essential? Even if they aren't, they should respawn in approximately in-game 10 to 30 days. I suggest you wait.

Comment: @Skye-AT: Unique NPCs do not respawn. If [Wujeeta](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Wujeeta) is dead, OP is out of luck and needs to reload an old save (or install some sort of cheat mod, which is possible on consoles, but I wouldn't know the details of that).

Comment: By NPC, you mean Wujeeta, right? If so, see: [Can you become the Thane of Riften if an NPC dies before you complete a quest that's required?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/46330/4797)